# I'm having a firefox issue with dropdown menu in an iframe, maybe a bug

Tags: firefox, iframe, dropdown

I have a form in an iframe for cc payment (paymetric).  The last field is expiration date from a dropdown list.  When the user cursors out of the frame back to my page and hits the submit button FireFox is requiring a click to activate the page then another click to submit.  In other words, it seems the user has to click twice on the next button.  Again, its only in firefox, and alas i have no live samples to show you :(  By the way, losing focus from an input box in the framed form this doesnt happen.

I've tried blur/focus onmouseout of frame, even tried jquery trigger('click') to no avail.  Any thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 0):

We have the same Issue - it is solved by cleaning up Firefox:

[image][image]

Comment: I submitted a bug for firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1365959